# Why is it I cant set a get variable

Tags: php, wordpress

I am appending ?readmore=true to the end of a url in wordpress

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>?readmore=true" class="readmore">
  <span><?php _e('Read more','MyProduct'); ?></span>
</a>
```

but on the next page I tried this

```
<?php
  print_r($_GET);
  if($_GET['readmore'] == "true") {
  get_header();
  }
?>
```

and in my print_r

I get this

```
 Array ( [page_id] => 8?readmore=true )
```

Am I missing something about get variables in wordpress

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to append **&readmore=true** instead of  **?readmore=true**.

Comment: And don't forget to put it there as an entity: `&amp;readmore=true`.